# Gather citations even though the list of authors is different

Tags: biblatex

How to gather the citation? I use `\cite{ref_by_author1_author2_author3, ref_by_author1_author4_author5}`.
I want the output

> author1 et al (year1, year2)

even though there might be more authors than just author1 and the additional authors might not be the same authors. I thought `uniquelist=false` could also differentiate in this case.

I have the settings as in [biblatex use et al. for more two authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262096/):

```
\usepackage[
natbib=true,
style=authoryear,
maxbibnames=3,
maxcitenames=2,
uniquelist=false,
firstinits=true,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Was it you who asked the other question? Is this resolved now? You want [`style=authoryear-comp,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp.pdf) or [`style=authoryear-icomp,`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/53-style-authoryear-icomp.pdf) instead of `style=authoryear` for compressed citations, the latter also uses "ibid" for directly subsequent citations, while the formed does not.

Comment: Yes, that was me. Sorry for the confusion. style=authoryear-comp does exactly what I want. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't suppose [that (only use one author, biblatex)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261887/35864) was you as well?

Comment: If the answer below helped you (whcih I gather it did), please consider accepting it using the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

For compressed citation lists you can use the `...-comp` styles.
The `biblatex` standard styles `numeric`, `authoryear` and `authortitle` all offer a `...-comp` version for compressed citations. The latter two also have `...-icomp` versions that additionally replaces successive citations of the same work with ibidem.

You want [`authoryear-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp.pdf).

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  natbib=true,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxbibnames=3,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false,
  firstinits=true,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\citet{baez/article,baez/online}
\end{document}
```

Gives just

> Baez und Lauda (2004a,b)